# Why does calling StaticLayout.Builder throw the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, builder, staticlayout

Android M has changed the setters for StaticLayout and instead we have the Builder pattern. But with the following code:

```
StaticLayout staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder.obtain("Hello", 0, "Hello".length(), getTextPaint(), 100).build();
```

I get the following exception:

> Process: sharpdevs.com.legalapp, PID: 7695
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;

I've tried everything, could this be an Android bug or am I missing a support library dependency?

Comment: This may sound a little obvious, but are you sure you're running the code on an Android M/6.0 device?

Comment: You're right, I don't know how I missed the obvious, thought I was running an API 23 emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this questions has already been solved in the comments, so to add it as an actual answer...

[`StaticLayout.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.Builder.html) was added in API 23, so trying to run it on an earlier API will cause an exception. You can use the standard [`StaticLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) constructors for earlier API versions.